# PageSpeed Insights won't return a result — Lighthouse error

Tags: google-chrome, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

For all of our internal pages, PageSpeed returns:

> Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: Extension result empty. Lighthouse calling Page.navigate with https://www.dallasnews.com/news/politics/2020/05/12/fauci-warns-of-really-serious-risks-if-states-open-before-covid-19-cases-fall-should-texans-be-worried/ Uncaught (in promise) Error: Extension timed out. No call to exit() before render timeout. at wrs.Extension.onTimeout_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:5567:13) at http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:669:9 at Map.forEach () at chromium.DevTools.Connection.dispatchMessage (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:668:76) at chromium.DevTools.Connection.onJsonMessage_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:650:65) at :1:40

Can you please help me understanding this error message and possibly how to fix it?

Comment: Added tags, formatting, a question.

Answer (score 0):

This reason you are getting timeout error is due to the extremely slow page load is exceeding PageSpeed timeout limits.

Use Chrome developer tools in the Chrome browser. Find LightHouse & run that. I was able to do this fine on the URL you supplied. Performance is in single-digit and it tells you all the issues.

Lighthouse has generous timeout settings as it measures more parameters outside raw performance. This is why Lighthouse succeeds when Pagespeed times out.

Once you fix some of the issues and bring down the size of the payload, which is currently over 10MB for this page, you should start seeing PageSpeed work without issues.